# Camera controls iphone 4 blocked by overlayview

Tags: iphone, xcode, camera, overlay

In my camera function i have an custom overlayview, its is a square in the middle of the screen. Works all fine on the iphone 3gs but if I am launching it on my iphone 4 im getting troubles with the button to switch to the front camera, somehow it gets blocked by the overlayview. How to fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your overlay view is probably sitting in front of the camera controls in the view hierarchy.

Try setting the backgroundColor of your overlay view to something like [UIColor greenColor] and running your app to see if it is showing up over the camera control.  If you see that your app's new green background color is covering the camera control, it means that your view is blocking input events to the control, even when your view's background color is clear.  You'll need to resize and reposition your view's frame so it doesn't cover the camera control.

When you're done, just get rid of the line in your code where you're setting the background color of your view to green.

Answer (score 1):

Hay, same problem, but another solution:

```
your_overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
your_overlay.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```